# Ruby system arguments

Tags: ruby, shell, nmap

I'm trying to use `system` to run nmap from a ruby program. I want to escape some of the arguments to prevent shell injection so I'm using the following form:

```
system('nmap', '-sn', hostname)
```

This works fine, however I want to use the `-oX -` option to output xml to stdout. The following code doesn't seem to work though:

```
system('nmap', '-sn', '-oX -', hostname)
```

The `-oX -` argument seems to be ignored, can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: try this `system("nmap -sn -oX -#{hostname}")`

Comment: will that escape shell metacharacters in `hostname`?

Comment: `hostname` is ruby variable?

Comment: yes, may contain untrusted user input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `system` also escapes spaces in arguments, your system call with `-oX -` will effectively be called as

```
nmap "-sn" "-oX -" "example.com"
```

with the space being part of a single argument. It will thus not be considered a valid argument for nmap. To fix this, you actually have to pass it as two arguments. Here, the space in the single argument will not be escaped:

```
system('nmap', '-sn', '-oX', '-', hostname)
```